# Ag Grid headerClass overrides numericColumn type

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to set AG Grid header style using `headerClass:"ag-grid-total-header"` but it overrides `type: 'numericColumn`' - it shows the header cell value left aligned.

**columnDef**:

```
{ headerName: 'Total', field: 'Total', width: 125, sortable: true, type: 'numericColumn', headerClass:"ag-grid-total-header"}
```

**CSS**:

```
.ag-grid-total-header {
  text-align:right; /* It does not work */
  background-color: red; /* This works */
}
```

Is there any way to apply header style while preserving numericColumn type?

stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-huk1fp?file=app/my-grid-application/my-grid-application.component.ts

EDIT:

It works if I add `headerComponentParams`. However, the sorting does not work if I add `headerComponentParams`.

```
headerComponentParams : {
      template:
        '<div class="ag-cell-label-container" role="presentation">' +
        '<span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text"  role="columnheader"></span>' +
        '</div>'
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header class that is used for a numeric type header is `ag-numeric-header`. So, apply both your class `ag-grid-total-header` and `ag-numeric-header` classes to your column. Change your column definition to:

```
  {
    headerName: "Price",
    field: "price",
    type: "numericColumn",
    headerClass: ["my-header-class", 'ag-numeric-header']
  },
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-xhb5nn?file=app/my-grid-application/my-grid-application.component.ts).